How to parse Raw Value from smartctl linux
Trying to write a script in Unraid using hdd smart values. How Can I parse the RAW_VALUE of a sensor? In my case it is 45
I can get all the specific sensor data using:
smartctl -A /dev/sdg | grep Airflow_Temperature_Cel

Output:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0032   055   051   000    Old_age   Always       -       45

I am just trying to get the RAW_VALUE value of 45 to input into a variable.

smartctl -A /dev/sdg | awk '$1 == 190 { print $NF }' To get it into a variable, just use command-substitution myairflow=$(smartctl -A /dev/sdg | awk '$1 == 190 { print $NF }')

Of course got it right after I posted. In case anyone is wondering below is what I did.
smartctl -A /dev/sdg | grep Airflow_Temperature_Cel | grep -o '...$'

Glad you got it worked out, but note the double pipe, double grep spawns (creates) 2 additional processes that are avoided with awk. Now for a single call it doesn't matter, but pay attention to the number of processes you create -- especially if you create them in a loop. Also note the regex '...$' blindly grabs the last 3 characters in the line. If the airflow becomes 4 digits - you miss one, if it only has 2, you include the preceding space.
